# PDF: Multiple pages with different size on one page

Tags: linux, pdf, printing

I have a PDF with 6 pages (let's call dem A-F) in portrait format.

The pages have two different sizes:

- A,C,D,F: 101.5mm x 215.5mm
- B,E:9.9mm x 215.5mm (so they are a bit narrower)

Now I want to merge them to two pages (302mm x 215.5mm).

```
Page 1:
_____________________________
|         |       |         |
|         |       |         |
|    A    |   B   |    C    |
|         |       |         |
|         |       |         |
|_________|_______|_________|
Page 2:
_____________________________
|         |       |         |
|         |       |         |
|    D    |   E   |    F    |
|         |       |         |
|         |       |         |
|_________|_______|_________|
```

When I try pdfnup I get white borders between the files.

```
pdfjam --suffix "print" --nup '3x1' --papersize "{302mm,215.5mm}" Dokument-2.pdf
```

Is there a better way to print multiple pages (with different sizes) on one sheet without resizing the pages?

Comment: somewhat related (since `pdfjam` is a frontend to `pdfpages`): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145713/stitch-differently-sized-pages-together

Comment: @myrdd guess I could have used this instead as it looks more reliable. I'll keep it in mind if I ever need to create a flyer again.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is also looking for an answer:

I now tried to do it with *podofoimpose* (which is a part of the [podofo-tools](http://podofo.sourceforge.net/about.html#tools)).
My plan is:

```lua
inch = 72
mm = inch / 25.4

smallWidth = 99 * mm
largeWidth = 101.5 * mm

PageHeight = 215.5 * mm
PageWidth = 302 * mm

if(PageCount == 6)
then
    i = 1
    newPage = 1
    while newPage &lt;= 2
    do
        x = 0
        while i &lt;= newPage * 3
        do
            -- PushRecord(sourcepage, targetpage, rotation, x, y)
            PushRecord(i, newPage, 0, x, 0)
            print(i, newPage, 0, x, 0)
            if(i == 2 or i == 5)
            then
                x = x + smallWidth
            else
                x = x + largeWidth
            end
            i = i + 1
        end
        newPage = newPage + 1
    end
end
```

To convert the pdf I now execute:

```
podofoimpose input.pdf output.pdf plan.lua
```

It is not perfect (some transparency is not preserved), but it works fine for now.